# Check if value in row is present in other columns within same row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How can i check if the value in Column `A2` or `B2` exists in Column `C2`, `D2`, or `E2`? I would like to highlight the value that is present more than once in the row.

Here is an example spreadsheet. [link to spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10QLwmNmgavAp8pfStssC04QEiqU0Ng0bauIc5Qqi4X8/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: In cell F2 type `=COUNTIF(C2:E2,A2)` and in column G2 type `=COUNTIF(C2:E2,B2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to `Format => Conditional Formatting`

The parameters are the following:

- range: `A2:E4`
- format rules: `custom formula`
- formula: `=COUNTIF($A2:$E4, INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN(), 4))) > 1`

The formula will highlight the duplicated values by row. The result can be seen below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One more option without using `INDIRECT`:

```
=ArrayFormula((OR(--(TRANSPOSE($A2:$B2)=$C2:$E2))*OR(A2=$A2:$B2)))
```

[image]